# What will we get from servlet if posted value is from an empty textbox

Tags: servlets, post

I'm trying to post some value to servlet in jsp, but when I post an empty textbox and do a check that value from servlet, it seems not catch a null value, but something else. 
If post an empty textbox, what will we get from servlet `request.getParameter("something");`

Comment: Empty string, i.e. ""

Comment: @developerwjk ya, null is not working but '' works